# Issues with custom DataPager

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, datapager

I am trying to extend the asp.net `DataPager` control into a custom control with predefined templates. This is the desired output

[image]

**Problems**:

1. When I load the page containing the custom DataPager for the first time, the `SelectMethod` of my `ObjectDataSource` is called 3 times.
2. When I try to load another page of data using the DataPager, the SelectMethod is called twice.
3. When I try to load another page of data, either by using the Next/Previous buttons or the DropDownList, the page does not change. I ran some debugging and found that it was not passing the correct value to the StartRowIndexParameter of the SelectMethod (it just passed 0 everytime it called the method).

Here's the code for my custom control.

```
public class DataPagerDDL : DataPager
{
    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        //add custom template
        TemplatePagerField templateField = new TemplatePagerField();
        templateField.PagerTemplate = new CustomTemplate();
        Fields.Add(templateField);

        //add previous/next page template
        NextPreviousPagerField nextPreviousField = new NextPreviousPagerField();            
        nextPreviousField.ShowFirstPageButton = false;
        nextPreviousField.ShowLastPageButton = false;
        nextPreviousField.PreviousPageText = "<<";
        nextPreviousField.NextPageText = ">>";
        Fields.Add(nextPreviousField);

        base.RenderContents(writer);
    }

    public void cmbPage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList cmbPage = (DropDownList)sender;
        this.SetPageProperties(cmbPage.SelectedIndex * MaximumRows, MaximumRows, true);
    }
}

public class CustomTemplate : ITemplate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Insert an instance of text and controls into the specified container.
    /// </summary>
    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        DataPagerFieldItem caller = (DataPagerFieldItem)container;
        DataPagerDDL pager = (DataPagerDDL)caller.Parent;
        int totalPages = pager.TotalRowCount / pager.MaximumRows;
        if (pager.TotalRowCount % pager.MaximumRows > 0) totalPages += 1;
        int currentPage = (pager.StartRowIndex / pager.MaximumRows) + 1;

        DropDownList cmbPage = new DropDownList();
        cmbPage.ID = "cmbPage";
        cmbPage.AutoPostBack = true;
        cmbPage.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(pager.cmbPage_SelectedIndexChanged);
        for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
        {
            ListItem item = new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
            if (i == currentPage) item.Selected = true;
            cmbPage.Items.Add(item);
        }

        pager.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Page "));
        pager.Controls.Add(cmbPage);
        pager.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" of " + totalPages.ToString() + " pages | "));
    }
}
```

And this is what my page looks like:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" DataSourceID="ods1" ... >
...
</asp:ListView>

<custom:DataPagerDDL ID="CustomDataPager" runat="server" PagedControlID="ListView1" 
        PageSize="25">
</custom:DataPagerDDL>    

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ods1" ... >
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

What should I do to make my custom DataPager work as intended? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're creating the pager fields too late in the page lifecycle. Try creating them from the `Init` event of the `DataPagerDDL` class.

Also, your `CustomTemplate` should be adding the controls to the `container`, not the `pager`.

```
public class DataPagerDDL : DataPager
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateDefaultPagerFields();
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    protected virtual void CreateDefaultPagerFields()
    {
        //add custom template
        TemplatePagerField templateField = new TemplatePagerField();
        templateField.PagerTemplate = new CustomTemplate();
        Fields.Add(templateField);

        //add previous/next page template
        NextPreviousPagerField nextPreviousField = new NextPreviousPagerField();            
        nextPreviousField.ShowFirstPageButton = false;
        nextPreviousField.ShowLastPageButton = false;
        nextPreviousField.PreviousPageText = "<<";
        nextPreviousField.NextPageText = ">>";
        Fields.Add(nextPreviousField);
    }

    public void cmbPage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList cmbPage = (DropDownList)sender;
        SetPageProperties(cmbPage.SelectedIndex * MaximumRows, MaximumRows, true);
    }
}

public class CustomTemplate : ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        DataPagerFieldItem caller = (DataPagerFieldItem)container;
        DataPagerDDL pager = (DataPagerDDL)caller.Parent;
        int totalPages = pager.TotalRowCount / pager.MaximumRows;
        if (pager.TotalRowCount % pager.MaximumRows > 0) totalPages += 1;
        int currentPage = (pager.StartRowIndex / pager.MaximumRows) + 1;

        DropDownList cmbPage = new DropDownList();
        cmbPage.ID = "cmbPage";
        cmbPage.AutoPostBack = true;
        cmbPage.SelectedIndexChanged += pager.cmbPage_SelectedIndexChanged;

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
        {
            ListItem item = new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
            if (i == currentPage) item.Selected = true;
            cmbPage.Items.Add(item);
        }

        container.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Page "));
        container.Controls.Add(cmbPage);
        container.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" of " + totalPages + " pages | "));
    }
}
```

Comment: Spot on, thank you! Is it generally advised to set the control's properties on Init? What if the control has additional custom properties e.g. `UserName` property on a `Label`? I have another custom control and I tried setting the properties on Init, but it didn't work. I think it's because the custom property's value (which is set in the HTML markup) is not retrieved until after the Load event. Am I right?

Comment: Setting properties in the control's `Init` event is largely equivalent to setting them in the page markup. The property values won't be stored in `ViewState`, so you'll have to set them on every request; don't wrap the code in an `if (!IsPostBack)` block. When you're dynamically modifying the control tree, the `Init` event is generally the latest point at which you want to make your changes, to ensure that the dynamic controls can participate in the post-back event processing.

Comment: Taking the `OnInit` approach solved an unrelated problem for me.  I was using `CreateChildControls()` to instantiate the template.  This worked fine except in the case where there was no data.  For some reason this call would cascade on itself and result in a stack-overflow.  Refactoring code to instantiate in the manner of this post solved the issue.