# How to style an ASP VB Datapager with Bootstrap pagination

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to do this:
[Formatting an asp:DataPager to show in ul li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394686/formatting-an-aspdatapager-to-show-in-ul-li) but i don't understand how do it in VB as that is C#. I was going to ask the accepted answerer but i can't comment so had to create a new question, sorry.

Comment: Did you try a [Code Translator](http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/)? They may not be able to translate at 100% accuracy, but you can probably fix the small remaining errors yourself.

Comment: I don't know where to put the code once it is converted though

Comment: It says in [the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13398968/5836671) how to implement the custom control.